# JavaScript: SplitAtFirst(':')

Tags: javascript, split

I have a lookup (static) like,

```
LookupValue = ['Something: A', 'Something: B', 'Something: C', 'Something: D: Classified Group 1', 'Something: D: Classified Group 2', 'Something: D: Classified Group 3', 'Anything: X', 'Anything: Y']
```

Code goes here to map the lookupfamily and its value,

```
MapValue = LookupValue().reduce(function (map, item) {
            var key = item.split(':')[0];
            map[key] = map[key] || [];
            map[key].push(item.split(':')[1] || []);            
            return map;
        }, {});
```

Actual Result:

```
MapValue
{...}
    __proto__: {...}
    Something: [ A, B, C, D, D, D]
    Anything: [X, Y]
```

Expected Result:

```
MapValue
{...}
    __proto__: {...}
    Something: [ A, B, C, D: Classified Group 1, D: Classified Group 2, D: Classified Group 3]
    Anything: [X, Y]
```

Is there any possibility to use this like, `map[key].push(item.splitAtFirst(':')[1] || [])`

Any suggestion on this would be very helpful.

Comment: Remove the first item from the array of split parts, and join the rest together again …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you,

```
MapValue = LookupValue.reduce(function (map, item) {
        var key = item.split(':')[0];
        map[key] = map[key] || [];
        map[key].push(item.substring(key.length + 1) || []); // Change is here
        return map;
    }, {});
```

`Split()` will give you array of strings. Instead specifically saying to take second element(`key[1]`), you can remove the first element, which is the key(`+1 for ':'`), from the original string(`item`)

Comment: That's Awesome !! Thanks much !!

Answer (score 0):

with lodash:

```
 var grouped = _.groupBy(LookupValue,q=>q.substring(0,q.indexOf(':')))
    Object.keys(grouped).forEach(key=>{  grouped[key] = grouped[key].map(x=>x.substring(x.indexOf(':')+1,x.length).trim())})
```